# WordPress login screen database issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

My WordPress login page at mysite.com/wp-login.php is giving me a `cannot connect to 127.0.0.1` error.

The site works, and other WordPress admin pages are available, like `upgrade.php`. I've done some googling, tried some of the suggestions here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-establishing-a-database-connection-112

But to no avail. Admin has been working for weeks and nothing has been changed. Everything also looks correct in config.php. The site is on AN Hosting, and I logged into the phpMyAdmin on the cPanel and everything seems to be in order with the database

I have very little experience with database issues and MySQL, so I am a little flummoxed.

Comment: Just a note. I did move the Wordpress installation from a 'dev' folder to the site root when the site launched, could that cause this issue? It has been working since then without incident for over a month.

Comment: Could you edit you question and add this note, its an important one, and it may cause trouble if not this one, it can be other, and I've answered before seen it :(, well check out my answer if it doesn't help, leave me a comment

Comment: Hi Chris, just wondering if you got to try my solution? I'm curious if it would've worked for you. Because it seemed like they were only blocking your log-in page from connecting to the database, so making a custom one could've possibly worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem. AN Hosting is blocking you. They are blocking *any* attempt to login on some of their shared servers. I changed wp-login.php page to a new address, and corrected all references in the WordPress folder.

Now everything works fine. However, it will only work until the next update.

AN Hosting says they are doing this only temporarily because they've been facing some type of attack on WordPress logons. If you ask me this is very lame. They need to resolve this issue.

Call them! I will also call them again and complain.

Comment: Hi - check-out my answer to see if that would work for you. It should provide an update-proof way of going-around the issue.

Comment: This must have been the issue. Suddenly started working. Thanks! Will be aware of this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thats strange if it was working before, and not now.

> I'm used to get trouble connecting to my database with WordPress *(since I'm installing WordPress websites many oftern)*, but when ever it failed for me the problem were in the hostname

I would suggest you to check your database hostname, if you can log in to cPanel you can find out form the data base interface

**Look here:**

[image]

**Then check this section for the hostname:**

[image]

**If you specified correctly there should be no problem**

---

After seen the comment you left after your question, this came to my mind

Go into

> **PhpMyAdmin** -> **Your WP Database** -> **Options Table** and check the site url value, it might be still pointing to your old **dev** url

Answer (score 0):

So based on the answer given by @user3035755 , I can give you the following work-around:

In your root directory, create a file called(for instance - you can change that if you want to) `login.php`(not sure if the word "login" would be accepted - you might have to play around with it a bit, until something works). In this file add the following code:

```
<?php
include_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-login.php' );
```

This code will include the original wp-login.php file. I'm not sure how their restriction works - if it's based on where the call to the database is being made(as in from which exact file), then it might fail due to the fact that the connection would still be made from `wp-login.php`(although I assume that's not how they did it). If they instead check the file that is being executed, then you should be fine(since in that case it would be `login.php` - again, you might have to change that).

Now, that's just the first step - you can either manually go to login.php every time you want to log-in, but it'd be better if the login URL is automatically adjusted. To do that, go to the `/wp-content/` directory and create(if it doesn't already exists) a `mu-plugins`<sup>1</sup> directory. In there create a new file, called new-login.php and in that file put the following code:

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: New Login URL
    Plugin Description: Makes the login URL /login.php instead of /wp-login.php
*/
function nl_login_url_filter( $login_url ) {
    return str_ireplace( home_url( '/wp-login.php' ), home_url( '/login.php' ), $login_url );
}
add_filter( 'login_url', 'nl_login_url_filter', 10 );

function nl_logout_url( $logout_url ) {
    return str_ireplace( home_url( '/wp-login.php' ), home_url( '/login.php' ), $logout_url );
}
add_filter( 'logout_url', 'nl_logout_url', 10 );
```

So what happens in this plugin, is that it simply hooks to the `login_url` and `logout_url` filters and changes `http://mydomain.com/wp-login.php?test1=23&test4=56` to `http://mydomain.com/login.php?test1=23&test4=56`.

This way you don't have to take care of always entering login.php instead of wp-login.php.

Again - if that doesn't work, try using a different name for the file, like `enter.php`(for instance), just remember to change the file name in the `new-login.php` file as well.

---

**Footnotes:**

1. The /wp-content/mu-plugins/ directory is a special directory. All .php files directly inside it(not in a sub-directory) get included in alphabetical order. So basically any plugin you put in there will always be enabled(the only way to disable a mu-plugin is to delete it's file in the mu-plugins directory). You can read more about mu-plugins [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)

Answer (score 0):

Been there done that, but that does not mean my guide-lines have the same positive result
for you but maybe it helps a little. Below a small roadmap with steps you could take:

These 2 (site url and home) you could add in wp_config.php.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://yoursite.com');// blog url
define('WP_SITEURL','http://yoursite.com'); // site url
```

Did it make any change for login? maybe you check the phpMyAdmin (*through cPanel*).

Check `wp_options` ( the `$table_prefix  = '???_'` ??? is what you have put there,
you find it in wp-config.php).

Now look at line 1 `option_id` 1 / `option_name` siteurl / `option_value` here must be your domain url.

Now find around line 36 `option_id` 36 / `option_name` home / `option_value` here should be your domain url.
IF they where not correct I assume you made corrections, saved them into the db and check if you are able to login now.
Stil not working? maybe following would good to check also:

What the .htaccess file shows (correct path?)

Add if not already done some debug "stuff" in wp_config.php:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); // Or false to disable
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); // writes errors down in wp-content/debug.log
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true ); // shows errors on screen output, set to false so only write into logfile
define('SAVEQUERIES', true); // will have a performance impact  so disable if not needed
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true); // Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
}
```

If no debug.log is shown in wp-content you create the file by hand.

Btw, is the wp-login.php having the correct chmod? (644 it should be)

Do you have/use cache plugins if so, could try to disable it by renaming folder.

Do you have some caching options through .htaccess if so, disable it for the moment.

Do you use a login plugin or script? If so, disable it for the moment being.

You could check functions.php (in your theme folder) if there is some code-snippet which could do a redirect for your wp-login.php, if so disable it for the moment.

Last but not least, if all above still not was solving your problem you could rename the plugins folder for a moment and try to login. (don't forget tot rename it back afterwards)

I hope that one of these will help you to find the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Ask your hosting provider what your database host should be and update the `DB_HOST` line in `wp-config.php` accordingly.

This is usually `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` but on some hosts it may be something completely different that you would not be able to guess without asking - for example I've had long weird hostnames supplied by GoDaddy for this before (years ago when I still used GD for anything).

Comment: The OP states "...The site works, and other Wordpress admin pages are available..." this means, that there is no way the issue is related to the configuration file, since WordPress is able to connect to the database(everywhere, except on wp-login.php).